# Pass type template as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to pass a generic type as an argument of the other type in such way, that I'll be able to specify different generic parameters there:

```
interface ISmth<Child extends Base> {
    doSmth(): Child<string>
    doSmthElse(): Child<number>
}
```

How can I doo that?

[Full demo code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QDwBVkC8yAriANYgD2A7iAHzIDeAsAFDIfIBucANsRABcyXAG42AXzZtQkWIhQBhABbBeAEwCMeQiXJVaDCAA9IIdRjSYcuBi3ac4AIwTCQxALZPo41lNYy4NDwSMgqauoATDpEpBQ09MgmZhZWWHh2bJzIxgCeAF7CGGBQoADmvv6BciEoAJIAyh5gytjhGkmmEOaW6FiZDhzqlE0tABQAlMLt6sgA9HNhqhrYxaUgZXRZnMOjygCivFiT08uzC0sR2O5e0Ft+0qwIvJiWe5rIwB4ADrwQHt0wJZGs1WjNNANsrtQZMmNtshwoBAwMQoCAmNw+AJhAAiACOBJxABpkM5XMgAMzIfzZGk7Eagw7HCZwwYIpEotEYnj8ITIAAskRJZOEAE5RdT4ZKHgEni8MG9QZFPj8-gDwMC9m0zpFIfS9rD7AjOBzUejGJjebiCXjiTkCtbCdLaVLoS0mRBDVLsqauRaedjKRSKSS8oVkDjqFGcc7OP5-EA)

```
interface Base<T = unknown> {
    value: T;
}

interface Child1<T = unknown> extends Base<T> {
    abc: number;
}

interface Child2<T = unknown> extends Base<T> {
    xyz: string;
}

interface ISmth<Child extends Base> {
    doSmth(): Child // Child<string>
    doSmthElse(): Child // Child<number>
}

class Smth1 implements ISmth<Child1> {
    doSmth() {
        return { value: "qqq", abc: 3 }
    }
    doSmthElse() {
        return { value: 42, abc: 99 }
    }
}

class Smth2 implements ISmth<Child2> {
    doSmth() {
        return { value: "qqq", xyz: "qqq" }
    }
    doSmthElse() {
        return { value: 333, xyz: "www" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want higher kinded types, which TypeScript doesn't really support.  There's an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) asking for this, but it's been open for a long time and I don't see any obvious signs of movement there.  Still, if you want it, you might go there and give it a .

If your generic `Child` can be constrained to a finite list of possible subclasses of `Base`, then you can rewrite your types in terms of a mapping like this:

```
interface ChildMapping<T> {
    Child1: Child1<T>,
    Child2: Child2<T>
    // add more here when you have them
}
```

Then you would identify these child classes by key/name and avoid the need for higher kinded types:

```
interface ISmth<K extends keyof ChildMapping<any>> {
    doSmth(): ChildMapping<string>[K];
    doSmthElse(): ChildMapping<number>[K];
}
```

You can test that it works:

```
class Smth1 implements ISmth<"Child1"> {
    doSmth() {
        return { value: "qqq", abc: 3 }
    }
    doSmthElse() {
        return { value: 42, abc: 99 }
    }
}

class Smth2 implements ISmth<"Child2"> {
    doSmth() {
        return { value: "qqq", xyz: "qqq" }
    }
    doSmthElse() {
        return { value: 333, xyz: "www" }
    }
}
```

It's not fully general, of course, since you'd be required to add a property to `ChildMapping` for each generic subclass of `Base` that you want to support, and you're using keys and not types (this can be [worked around with conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-415694540) but it doesn't seem worth it to me), but it might be an acceptable substitute for higher kinded types until and unless they ever show up in the language.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QDwBUB8yA3gLABQylyAbnADYCuEAXMrgNzkC+5y5okWIhQBhABbA6AEwCMeQhAAekEFIxpMOAsV5U4AIwSsQDALb7onMjzL9w0eEmTjJUgEzzkSlWo1ZPpBRUigCeAF6sGGBQoADmVjZ2go6iEtIAsnAADllxAbqULtIyrEWy8gA0Bc5p7qW1HgTc5EkOwsgAkgDKpmBi2ADSXsoQquoA1hAhAPYwNa6ZOXlwICH4hIFUyFLTPX0AFACU9QvZuSCx2FExF-gA2gMAulZbO3tiAKJ0WEcnGWd5EzmaD3J4JFpkBB0TDqd4yZDAUxZOgQUyjMDqbq9foAIjKMhxG2qb2xRx0QS2lCgEDADCgIGINHoTFYOIAjhycRVkAYjMgAMzIGxbYVUEl9L4-Q7kylUam0+mM2iMFjIAAsbm5vNYAE4dULqjZEpDoRhYdi3AikSi0eBMe9sHiGoSZWLdqTpZtZch5XSGUQmSrWRy2VzkKEIsh2ZyDRTY693RLvhAyV7Zb7FQHlSyBfz+dyI6yAO4lnHxqhG8hAA)

Comment: Great! I have only 2 child classes and such mapping may even simplify other code. Generics are great, but they cause the code to grow very much when are used nested...